# How to validate json string in PHP like JSON_VALID in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, json, validation

I would like to validate json string before inserting it into mysql database so that JSON_VALID constraint is not violated. Using json_decode like

```
json_decode($string, true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
```

is not enough because

```
json_decode('["\u001f?\b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0002\u0003KL)NKLI\u0003\u0000z,?o\u0007\u0000\u0000\u0000"]', true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
```

throws no error but

```
select JSON_VALID('["\u001f?\b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0002\u0003KL)NKLI\u0003\u0000z,?o\u0007\u0000\u0000\u0000"]') as result;
```

returns false. How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: jsonlint.com says it's valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON is valid, that's why the PHP version doesn't throw an error. But in SQL you need to escape all the backslashes to make them literal, so they'll be seen by the JSON parser. This is why MySQL mistakenly claimed it's not valid.

```
> select JSON_VALID('["\\u001f?\\b\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0002\\u0003KL)NKLI\\u0003\\u0000z,?o\\u0007\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000"]') as result; 
+--------+
| result |
+--------+
|      1 |
+--------+
```

Comment: He want to validate it using PHP.

Comment: Ok, so the problem was escaping.

Comment: @MuradAli The PHP is fine. I'm just showing why he got a different result in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

The string you calling a json string is a unicode. But you want to validate your json string using PHP so here is the code.

```
function json_validator($data=NULL) {

  if (!empty($data)) {

                @json_decode($data);
                return (json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE);
        }
        return false;
}

$jsonString = '["\u001f?\b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0002\u0003KL)NKLI\u0003\u0000z,?o\u0007\u0000\u0000\u0000"]';

echo (json_validator($jsonString) ? "JSON is Valid" : "JSON is Not Valid");
```

[Source](https://codeblogmoney.com/validate-json-string-using-php/)

Well this return true, but the string is an `escaped unicode` in a json style.

**Updated Method 2**

```
$jsonString = '["\u001f?\b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0002\u0003KL)NKLI\u0003\u0000z,?o\u0007\u0000\u0000\u0000"]';
try {
    json_decode($jsonString, true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // echo $e->getMessage();
    echo "Invalid JSON";
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the `JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR` flag serve the same purpose?

Comment: Yeah, we can use that I just add the second method.